# How to place two images in one canvas through java (not jframe)

Tags: java, image

I just want to place two different images on one canvas and make it a .jpg file in Java. I just want to make a resulting file, not a GUI.

[image: ![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3pd1G.jpg)][image]

I want to make a result file like below with both images above:

[image]

Comment: Do you have any code you've already written?

Comment: Hint: Create a Buffered image of the correct size, then simply write both images to it in the correct location. To get started, see the official tutorial on how to create the first image: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `BufferedImage` to combine the two images. The following code shows a simple implementation:

```java
public static void combineImages(String imagePath1, String imagePath2, String outputPath) throws IOException {
    int intervalWidth = 20; // The interval between two images
    BufferedImage image1 = ImageIO.read(new File(imagePath1));
    BufferedImage image2 = ImageIO.read(new File(imagePath2));
    int combinedWidth = image1.getWidth() + image2.getWidth() + intervalWidth;
    int combinedHeight = Math.max(image1.getHeight(), image2.getHeight());
    BufferedImage combined = new BufferedImage(combinedWidth, combinedHeight, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    Graphics2D g = combined.createGraphics();
    g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    // Fill the background with white
    g.fillRect(0, 0, combinedWidth, combinedHeight);
    // Draw the two images on the combined image
    g.drawImage(image1, 0, 0, null);
    g.drawImage(image2, image1.getWidth() + intervalWidth, 0, null);
    ImageIO.write(combined, "jpg", new File(outputPath));
}
```